# Automapper - Map Complex object from Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, automapping

I'm trying to map this:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    ["Address.City"] = "New York",
    ["FirstName"] = "First Name",
    ["LastName"] = "Last Name"
};
```

into this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

If I don't change any config, I get `Address` as null. I've tried different approaches. A resolver or just editing my dictionary in the `MapperConfiguration` like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    const string addressPrefix = "Address.";

    cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, Person>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Address, x => x.MapFrom(c => new Dictionary<string, object>(c.Where(dic => dic.Key.StartsWith(addressPrefix)).ToDictionary(dic => dic.Key.Replace(addressPrefix, string.Empty), dic => dic.Value))));

    cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, Person>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<PersonResolver>());
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var person = mapper.Map<Person>(values);
```

Both cases I successfully get the `Address` mapped right, but I lose the First and Last Name. Is there a way to reset the mapper to default for other members?

My resolver:

```
public class PersonResolver : IValueResolver<IDictionary<string, object>, Person, Address>
{
    public Address Resolve(IDictionary<string, object> source, Person destination, Address destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        const string addressPrefix = "Address.";
        var address = new Address();

        if (source.Keys.Any(x => x.StartsWith(addressPrefix, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)))
        {
            var addressItems = source
                .Where(dic => dic.Key.StartsWith(addressPrefix, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                .ToDictionary(dic => dic.Key.Replace(addressPrefix, string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCulture), dic => dic.Value);

            address = context.Mapper.Map<Address>(addressItems);
        }
        return address;
    }
}
```

Comment: The dictionary you are trying to map from has the same key used for First name and Last name

Comment: Try a map from string to Address as the only config.

Comment: @MrBrown this was just a typo. I've been playing around for a while

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I've tried with a bunch of different setups

Comment: The only thing is, the key must be "Adress".

Comment: @BrunoAvelar : Have you found a way to do this ?

Comment: @AlexandreLocas Sorry, I don't think I did. I'd come back to post the solution :(